# Android: Utilizing ListFragments for displaying pre made Database

Tags: android, database, android-listfragment, slidingmenu

I'm a beginner and just beginning to understand android programming.

I'm utilizing the SlidingMenu libraries and I'm trying to list items in the fragment as shown. (Items displayed are merely strings)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/46/screenshot2013021419134.png/

However, when I try to extract data from a pre made database and list the items as mentioned, I'm stuck with a never ending loading.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot2013021923094.png/

Here are my codes..

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // All related with slidingMenu
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setBehindContentView(R.layout.primary_view);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.primary_view, new FragList())
    .commit();

    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.secondary_view);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.secondary_view, new WorshipFragList())
    .commit();
    sm.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    if (null != searchView )
    {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);   
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

```
class SongHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DATABASE_PATH = "";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DataDB";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "song";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";

public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myContext;
Cursor cursor;

public SongHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void createDatabase() {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() {

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();

    if(!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDBFromResource();
    }
}

private boolean DBExists() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Log.e("SqlHelper", "Database not found");

    }

    if (db!=null) {
        db.close();
    }

    return db!= null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDBFromResource() {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try {

        inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");
    }
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (dbSqlite != null)
    {
        dbSqlite.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> getTableColumn(String TABLE_NAME, String[] column){

    ArrayList<String> aL = new ArrayList<String>();

    cursor = dbSqlite.query(TABLE_NAME, column, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      aL.add(cursor.getString(0));
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    System.out.println(aL);
    cursor.close();
    return aL;
}

public String getName(Cursor c) {

    return(c.getString(1));

}
```

}

```
    public class FragList extends ListFragment {

SongHelper dbSongHelper = null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    dbSongHelper = new SongHelper(getActivity());
}
```

}

Help is very much appreciated to find a solution for this problem..

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, any help? Been working on this for days already :(